# javascript/typescript save external link images in PDF file

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to print my webpage as a PDF file.
I tried html2canvas and jsPDF, it requires dataurl to print stuff.

Since I display images directly from URL, some of these websites do not enable CORS, I can't use the toDataUrl method to transfer images to dataurl, is there a workaround to do it? Or are there any other libraries I can use?

Comment: see this https://wkhtmltopdf.org/

Comment: this is not js/angular library. I want it to run with a button click in my webpage.

Comment: If remote url's don't accept cross origin requests the only way is using some server code, or older browsers. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Comment: May I know the server code that I have to use?

Comment: In this case is pretty easy `wkhtmltopdf http://google.com google.pdf`